# Batch file - if not exist not working

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I have a problem whereby I am trying to determine if given directory exists on file system before attempting to download a file.

batch file:

```
:: Create Apache Directory if does not exist
mkdir "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache" 2> nul

:: Setup Apache Ant if Ant does not exist
if not exist "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\apache-ant-1.9.7\" (
    :: Set filename variable
    SET "FILENAME=%~dp0\apache-ant-1.9.7-bin.zip"

    :: Download ANT from mirror
    bitsadmin.exe /transfer "Apache Ant Download" http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/ftp.apache.org//ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.7-bin.zip "%FILENAME%"

    :: Copy Apache Ant to C:\Apache-Ant
    xcopy "%~dp0apache-ant-1.9.7-bin.zip"  %HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\.

    :: Delete zip file from curent directory
    del "%~dp0apache-ant-1.9.7-bin.zip"

    :: Unzip Apache Ant to C:\Apache-Ant
    call :UnZipFile "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\" "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\apache-ant-1.9.7-bin.zip"

    :UnZipFile <ExtractTo> <newzipfile>
    set vbs="%temp%\_.vbs"
    if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
    >%vbs%  echo Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    >>%vbs% echo If NOT fso.FolderExists(%1) Then
    >>%vbs% echo fso.CreateFolder(%1)
    >>%vbs% echo End If
    >>%vbs% echo set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    >>%vbs% echo set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace(%2).items
    >>%vbs% echo objShell.NameSpace(%1).CopyHere(FilesInZip)
    >>%vbs% echo Set fso = Nothing
    >>%vbs% echo Set objShell = Nothing
    cscript //nologo %vbs%
    if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%

    :: Delete zip folder
    del "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\apache-ant-1.9.7-bin.zip"

    :: Set ANT_HOME path
    setx ANT_HOME "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\apache-ant-1.9.7" /m

    :: Add ANT to path
    setx path "%PATH%;%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\apache-ant-1.9.7\bin" /m
)
```

Updated: I have added @aschipfl suggestion

the directory C:/Apache/apache-ant-1.9.7 DOES exist so the code should fail but when run it still downloads the file and tries to do further setups there. Any idea whats wrong and why the if statement is executed where it should not be ?

Thanks

Comment: I do not see how the `IF` command could be wrong but I do see another problem with your code.  You are setting a variable inside a code block but you are not using delayed expansion to use that variable in the next line of code.

Comment: @Squashman adding sleep is not a problem, but finding out why the block executes though it should not ? hmm

Comment: What are you talking about.  Sleep has nothing to do with my comment.  I am talking about the %filename% variable.  When you are inside a code block and you set a variable and you need to use that variable inside that code block, you need to use delayed expansion.

Comment: Your logic is flawed.  Your first `IF NOT EXIST` creates the directory **Apache** but your very next `IF NOT EXIST` checks Apache\apache-ant-1.9.7\.

Comment: Here is some information about [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)...

Comment: Actually there is no reason for checking whether a directory exists before creating it, simply write `mkdir "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache" 2> nul` (the last portion dismisses the error message in case the directory already existed)...

Comment: And I will make one more comment just because I have seen this happen time and time again.  You are only posting part of your code.  I can't tell you how many times people have only posted part of the code of their script and it turned out some code that executed previously was affecting the code they thought was wrong.

Comment: @Squashman missunderstanding, i thought you are referring to delay such as sleep. I have also added full bath. Apache directory is not the same as Apache\apache-ant-1.9.7\ You can have Apache directory that is empty (when ant is not installed for example)

Comment: You need to escape the parentheses you are using to create your VBscript.

Comment: @Squashman escaped but still the same behavior used ^^^) to escape btw

Comment: No.  You use one caret to escape the closing parentheses. `>%vbs%  echo Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^)`

Comment: Ultimately your original batch files is littered with errors. Which proves my original point that you should always post all of your code.

Comment: @Squashman indeed you are right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labels are not allowed within a block (series of instructions within parentheses)

an `md` will create intermediate directories if required.

Batch has no idea of procedures. If you `call` a subroutine, then when the subroutine ends (reaches end-of-file or an `exit`) execution will return to the instruction after the `call` - so `:UnZipFile` with your code.

Move the `:unzipfile` routine to the end-of-file and insert a `goto :eof` directly before it to ensure the code does not flow-through to `:unzipfile`.
Add a `goto :eof` to the end of `:unzipfile`so that you can add extra code (like more subroutines) later. `goto :eof` specifically means "go to physical end-of-file" which terminates the current routine.

note that `setx` does NOT affect the **current** environment, nor does it affect **existing** `cmd` instances, only **new** `cmd` instances, hence execute both `set` and `setx`.

```
if exist "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\apache-ant-1.9.7\" goto ant197exists
:: Setup Apache Ant if Ant does not exist
md "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\apache-ant-1.9.7\" 2>nul
:: Set filename variable
SET "FILENAME=%~dp0\apache-ant-1.9.7-bin.zip"

:: Download ANT from mirror
bitsadmin.exe /transfer "Apache Ant Download" http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/ftp.apache.org//ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.7-bin.zip "%FILENAME%"

:: Copy Apache Ant to C:\Apache-Ant
xcopy "%~dp0apache-ant-1.9.7-bin.zip"  "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\."

:: Delete zip file from curent directory
del "%~dp0apache-ant-1.9.7-bin.zip"

:: Unzip Apache Ant to C:\Apache-Ant
call :UnZipFile "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\" "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\apache-ant-1.9.7-bin.zip"

:: Delete zip folder
del "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\apache-ant-1.9.7-bin.zip"

:: Set ANT_HOME path
set "ANT_HOME=%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\apache-ant-1.9.7"
setx ANT_HOME "%HOMEDRIVE%\Apache\apache-ant-1.9.7" /m

:: Add ANT to path
set "path=%PATH%;%ant_home%"
setx path "%PATH%" /m

:ant197exists

....whatever whatever

goto :eof

:UnZipFile <ExtractTo> <newzipfile>
set vbs="%temp%\_.vbs"
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
>%vbs%  echo Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>>%vbs% echo If NOT fso.FolderExists(%1) Then
>>%vbs% echo fso.CreateFolder(%1)
>>%vbs% echo End If
>>%vbs% echo set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
>>%vbs% echo set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace(%2).items
>>%vbs% echo objShell.NameSpace(%1).CopyHere(FilesInZip)
>>%vbs% echo Set fso = Nothing
>>%vbs% echo Set objShell = Nothing
cscript //nologo %vbs%
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, but this still does not work the way i want to. Even though the directory exists script still tries to download and unzip the file.

Comment: apologies - ignore my comment, i was running wrong file ;/. Also thank you for explaining few bits and bobs :)